# Principle of Best Principles

Tags: ruby, oop

I seem to run into a couple of design issue a lot and I never know what 
is
really proper. On one hand I often hear that I should limit coupling and
stick to single responsibility, but when I do I often find it difficult 
to
get the information to part of the program when it is needed. For 
example,

```
class Singer
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  attr :name
end
```

Then should Song be:

```
class Song
  def new(singer)
    @singer = singer
  end
end
```

or

```
class Song
  def new(singer_name)
    @singer_name = singer_name
  end
end
```

The later has less coupling, so according to principles I should use it.
But if I later discover something in Song needs to know more about the
singer, I'm in a bad way. e.g.

```
 class Song
   ...
   def play
     puts "Belting it out by #{@singer.name}, winner of
     #{@singer.grammy_count} grammies!"
   end
 end
```

I'd be in a fix if I had used the later Song class instead of the 
former.
But then I suspect someone would remind me of SRP, single responsibility
principle, and suggest instead:

```
  class SongPlayer
    def initialize(singer, song)
      @singer, @song = singer, song
    end
    def play
      puts "Belting it out by #{@singer.name}, winner of
      #{@singer.grammy_count} grammies!"
    end
  end
```

And yea, I guess that makes sense, since another singer might do a cover 
of
some one else's song, right? But then, would it really be the exact same
song? In most of my cases it's never the same "song" so I never have 
that
kind of scenario. So is the SRP worth the extra classes it brings to the
code then?

I sometimes think many OOP principles, SOLID or otherwise, arose out
limitations of Java, and don't apply so well to Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Coupling* should be held up against another concept, [*cohesion*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CouplingAndCohesion). You want to strike a balance between the two, rather than just take one of them to the extreme. In your example, `singer_name` seems to belong to `Singer`, so to preserve cohesion, you should pass the `Singer` object to `Song`, rather than the `name`.

More generally, you need to keep in mind that such principles are merely guide lines. You always have to apply common sense and your unique understanding of the problem domain. There is rarely a clear cut case - It might even change as your application grows or as you understand the domain better.

Answer (score 2):

Object-oriented programs should model real-life objects. In life a song belongs to a singer, not to the singer's name and in your programs you should model it in this manner.

As @troelskn already mentioned there is the concept of coupling, but there is also the concept of cohesion... Principles are great, but common sense should take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has **programmer happiness** at its core. You should consider the readability of your code and how much it strains your(or your colleague's) brain, especially when you have to go through and understand it again after a long pause.

I'd say SRP should be taken as a recommendation and not a rule. If `SongPlayer` makes it harder to understand what's going on, just drop SRP and stick with `Song#play`, if it makes it easier, by all means, go with it.

And remember, you can always refactor. I'd start with `Song#play` and if `Song` begins to get bloated with playing-related code, then I'd refactor that stuff out to a `SongPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Singer to Song, this is true OOP way. Because, you are separating concerns, that's good.

As for your example, 'you should tell, dont ask'. So that, Song always be telling Singer to advertise itself like this:

```rb
class Song
  ...
  def play
    # So that, singer will use the template and add the details
    puts @singer.to_s("Belting it out by #{name}, winner of #{grammy_count} grammies!")
  end
end
```

This is my two cents.